# How to Use Scoped Storage with Ionic Vue

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, android-11, scoped-storage, ionic-vue

I'm using Ionic with Vue and Capacitor and my app should allow the user to record audio. I'm using the cordova-plugin-media for that but it tries to store a temporary recording in `/storage/emulated/0` which throws this error:

`W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/tmprecording-1624204719032.3gp: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)`

From what I've read, this is likely due to Android 11 making use of scoped storage and not allowing it to write. I don't know what to do about it (how to use scoped storage) from the Ionic-Vue project and would really appreciate some help.

Thank you!

Comment: I have the same issue with Ionic Angular :(

Comment: @franswa I’m not a 100% sure but I think scoped storage hasn’t been implemented in Ionic yet :( I ended up restarting from scratch using Android directly.

Comment: This is an issue from cordova-plugin-media, not really ionic. FYI it looks like this issue is one of their milestones from the version 6.0.0: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media/milestone/1